# C# WinForms minimize frm.Show() when main form is minimized

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Form that is showing an overlay form:

```
private void ShowWait()
{             
    frmOverlay = new Base.frmOverlay("Please Wait...");
    frmOverlay.Show(this);
}
```

This `frmOverlay` form at the same time is show it shows another form in the middle (message form):

```
private void frmOverlay_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    frmPleaseWait = new frmPleaseWait(_text); 
    frmPleaseWait.Show(this);
}
```

When I minimize the main form then I can still see the `frmPleaseWait` form, is there a way I can minimize all when the main form is minimized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a recursive function that will minimize all child forms.

```
public void MinimizeAllChildForms(Form parent)
{
    foreach(Form f in parent.OwnedForms)
    {
        f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        MinimizeAllChildForms(f);
    }
}
```

Then in your main form, call it from the `Resize` event.

```
void MainForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
       MinimizeAllChildForms(this);
}
```

I assume you want `frmPleaseWait` to also minimize when `frmOverlay` is minimized. If you don't, then you can simply set its parent to the main form instead so that it automatically minimizes when the main form does.

```
frmPleaseWait = new frmPleaseWait(_text); 
frmPleaseWait.Show(MainForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Eventhandler for the resize event and minimize your form in there:

```
Form2 f2 = null;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   f2 = new Form2(); 
   f2.Show();
}

private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        f2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
}
```

Add that code to your mainform and frmOverlay